# How to remove Traefik 2.0 Middleware and IngressRoute in kubernetes once deployed

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I have the following YAML (test.yaml) file that allows me to create ingress router and middleware for traefik 2

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: qa
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`my-url.com`) && PathPrefix(`/test`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: test
          port: 8000
      middlewares:
        - name: testmiddle
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: testmiddle
  namespace: qa
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes:
      - /test
```

Following files works. However, when I try to remove it using the following command:

```
kubectl delete -f test.yaml
```

Traefik complains that middleware and ingress router is not preset. Example of error as follows:

```
time="2021-07-09T18:15:12Z" level=error msg="middleware \"qa-test@kubernetescrd\" does not exist" routerName=qa-test-29c010046e0ec473d890@kubernetescrd entryPointName=web 
time="2021-07-09T18:15:25Z" level=error msg="middleware \"qa-test@kubernetescrd\" does not exist" entryPointName=web routerName=qa-test-29c010046e0ec473d890@kubernetescrd 
time="2021-07-09T18:15:25Z" level=error msg="middleware \"qa-test@kubernetescrd\" does not exist" entryPointName=web routerName=qa-test-29c010046e0ec473d890@kubernetescrd 
time="2021-07-09T18:31:44Z" level=error msg="middleware \"qa-test@kubernetescrd\" does not exist" entryPointName=web routerName=qa-test-29c010046e0ec473d890@kubernetescrd
```

Do you know how to remove middleware and ingress routers without error?

Comment: maybe try to edit and remove Middleware from IngressRoute first and then delete the Middleware and then the IngressRoute?

`kubectl edit ingressroute test -n qa; kubectl delete middleware testmiddle -n qa; kubectl delete ingressroute test -n qa`


since these are crd's, APIserver won't delete them in the right order when deleting from a file and you would see error messages in the logs

Comment: Can you please put that in answer. I will accept answer

Comment: @[kush Patel] added, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try editing the IngressRoute to remove Middleware from IngressRoute first and then delete the Middleware and then the IngressRoute.

```
kubectl edit ingressroute test -n qa; 
kubectl delete middleware testmiddle -n qa; 
kubectl delete ingressroute test -n qa
```

since these are crd's, API-server won't delete them in the right order when deleting from a file and you would see error messages in the logs.